# WiFi disconnected and hidden from SSID (available wifi network) list

Tags: release-freya, system, wifi

I've noticed that my WiFi would suddenly disconnected and not listed in the available WiFi network list. I have to turn on airplane mode/disable WiFi to get it connected back or listed in the list. The other way is to go to **Connect to Hidden WiFi network** and select my network from the list. A quick check on the listed question says mostly a realtek driver issue but I'm using Qualcomm Atheros. Below is my `lshw -c network`

```
*-network               
       description: Wireless interface  
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)  
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros  
       physical id: 0  
       bus info: pci@0000:43:00.0  
       logical name: wlan0  
       version: 01  
       serial: 78:e4:00:98:42:7c  
       width: 64 bits  
       clock: 33MHz  
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless  
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.19.0-28-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.67 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn  
       resources: irq:19 memory:d0700000-d070ffff
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it works fine for a period seems to indicate faulty power saving mode in the Ath9k driver. You can try to disable this with the following methods.

### **Disable WiFi Power Saving**

*Temporary*

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

(or)

```
sudo modprobe -r ath9k
sudo modprobe ath9k ps_enable=0
```

*Permanent*

```
sudo touch /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

Add `options ath9k ps_enable=0` as the last line

Comment: Shame. You could also try disabling hw encryption as mentioned in [this](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/unable-to-connect-to-own-wifi-network-freya?rq=1) question. Might pay for you to examine the contents of `dmesg` and `/var/log/syslog` immediately after a disconnect and post anything that seems related to the WiFi

Comment: unfortunately the solution does not work. I still experienced the wifi disconnection. When I use the command `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off`, I would get this  `Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C) :`  
    `SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.`

Comment: Will check on `dmesg` and `syslog` if it occurs again. What should I be looking for in the `syslog`?

Comment: Running `sudo modprobe -r ath9k` and `sudo modprobe ath9k ps_enable=0` really screwed up my wifi just now. The wifi connection kept on turn on, scanning and turn off. Had to reboot to get it back up again.

Comment: Good thing you didn't apply the permanent solution then. ;p In syslog you are looking for lines containing *wlan0, Ath9k, wpasupplicant or networkmanager* (amongst other things) corresponding with the time the issue occurs. If you run dmesg with the -T flag (`dmesg -T`) the timestamps will be in the same format as syslog. If in doubt post them in their entirety to pastebin or somewhere and just link to that.

Comment: I think I might have found the solution but haven't tried it yet. The guy have the same Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226484). He installed **Backport** from instruction here [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2211168&p=12963298#post12963298) and it solved his dropped wifi connection.