# Network-Adapter doesn't get used by system

Tags: release-freya, wifi, networking

I recently reinstalled Elementary OS (Freya 0.3.2) on my Laptop, but how ever the Networking seems not to work properly.

I've got a "Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter" which gets detected by the system as  *lspci*  shows, but in the Networksettings there isn't even a Wireless-Option.

This  [article](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/unable-to-connect-to-own-wifi-network-freya)  is what I found so far, the Output of  *lshw -c network*  is the same as mine. I tried the given solutions, but that doesn't changed anything.

Ethernet works just fine, but I would like to use wifi as before as well.
It isn't a problem with the router as the Ethernet-Connection shows and the system is completly newly setup.

So if anybody has an idea how to fix that, I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but with a different wireless card. I have a Macbook Air with the Broadcom 4360 wireless card.

I followed the instructions of [Ubuntu Community Wiki WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx), and in particular, reinstalling the drivers using the following command solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

The same for your wireless card might solve the problem.